# How to set maximum concurrency requests in camel cache

Tags: caching, apache-camel

I'm using camel cache to avoid external calls for same type of requests. But the problem is when many requests are trying to hit the same cache component at a time, all the request threads are getting unresponsive and apparently server is getting hanged.

Is there any way to set the max limit requests in cache component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I manged to resolve this issue.

This issue is not because of maximum hits to cache component, its because of deadlock happening within the cache component. So I found that there is no necessity of setting the max value concurrency hits to cache component.

Thanks